# Using R, how do I rotate a GeoTiff file with multiple bands and save it?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, rotate

[image]

My existing code (see below) only reads and rotates one band but I want all 360 of my bands to rotate.

```
library(raster)

your_raster <- raster("path/to/raster.tif")

rotated_raster <- rotate(your_raster)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load a multi-band raster up, don't use `raster()` function, use `brick()` or `stack()` instead. `raster()` only opens single-band rasters, even from a multi-band raster (you can set the band you want to open).

Rotate works with multi-band rasters, so you'll be fine after opening the file:

```
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
m <- matrix(1:ncell(r), nrow=18)
values(r) <- as.vector(t(m))
extent(r) <- extent(0, 360, -90, 90)
s <- stack(r,r,r)
rr <- rotate(s)

plot(s)
plot(rr)
```

[image]
[image]

Use `write.raster(rotated_raster,'path_/to/file.tif')` then for saving the file in your computer.